# What is the range of $(f+g)(x)$ where $f(x)=x^2+4x-3$ and $g(x)=3x^2-8x+9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

> What is the range of $(f+g)(x)$?

[image]

I plugged in the domain values to get the range for each of the equations and then I would have summed them up. But I'm getting erroneous results.

Because each function will have a different range, I believe we should first find these intervals and then get the sum.

The answer is given as $[5,30]$

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What makes this weird is that the domains of both functions are not the same... Are you supposed to just take the union of those domains? For example, what is $(f+g)(x)$ if $-4 < x < -2$, which is not in the domain of $f$? Genuine question because I've never seen this before (or, if I have, it's been way too long). My guess is either $f+g$ has a domain that is the union of both intervals, or that each of $f,g$ is considered $0$ outside of the domain, but I don't know. EDIT: Or another thought is the intersection of both intervals actually.

Comment: FWIW, graphing the two functions and their sum might help in this case.

Comment: The sum is defined on the intersection of the domains so we have to find the range of $f+g$ on $[-2,1)$.

Comment: This answer might help:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1569000/28816.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain is $[-2,5)\cap(-4,1)=[-2,1)$,
$$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=4x^2-4x+6=(2x-1)^2+5\geq5.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\frac{1}{2}\in[-2,1).$

Now, calculate $(f+g)(-2)$, $(f+g)(1)$ and get the answer.

I got $[5,30]$.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "the equality occurs for $x=\frac{1}{2}\in[-1,2]$"

Comment: @Eldar $(2x-1)^2\geq0$ for all real $x$. Also, $(2x-1)^2=0$ for $2x-1=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}.$ We see also that $-1\leq\frac{1}{2}\leq2.$

Comment: This answer is correct. Why the downvote? I gave +1$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I think because I made the typo. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: One thing I noticed now, when we plug in $1)$ into the equation $4x^2-4x+6$ shouldn't then the interval be $(6,30]$. Though the answer is given as $[5,30]$

Comment: @Eldar Rahimli $(f+g)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=5<6.$